# Jquery loaded before the jquery-dependent script, but the latter still says "$ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my HTML page, I have the following way of loading JS files:

```
<script id="jjquery"></script>
<script id="jscookie"></script>
<script id="winx"></script>

<script>
(function(){
  if(screen.width > 479) 
    document.querySelector("#jjquery").setAttribute("src", "/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js");
    document.querySelector("#jscookie").setAttribute("src", "/js/jscookie.js");
    document.querySelector("#winx").setAttribute("src", "/js/winx.js");
}());
</script>
```

Basically I used the way described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31848646/2418445) to only load certain scripts starting from the specific screen resolution. But the third script out of three, that relies on jquery, is not working and says `$ is not defined`. Even though if I enter `$` in the console, it returns normal response. And when I see the order of the scripts in the HTML output, it is clear that jquery is loaded prior to two other scripts. What could be the issue here?

P.S. everything works comlpetely fine if I just load the scripts normally without the resolution check.

Comment: When you change the `src`, there is a delay to load it. You will have to use a `load` event.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to use it. Would you please create an answer showing it? P.S. it mustn't rely on jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conditionally load javascript (external and internal) and keep execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973441/conditionally-load-javascript-external-and-internal-and-keep-execution-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the scripts are loaded asynchronously, so the order of your code isn't relevant.

You can see a [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts) of how you can properly import your scripts.

In your case, if some of your scripts depend on jquery, you can create an `onLoadJquery` function and append it as the `onload` attribute of the script, this function will be executed after the import.

```
<script>
(function(){
  if(screen.width > 479) { 
    // add the callback that will be executed once jquery is loaded
    document.querySelector("#jjquery").addEventListener("load", onLoadJquery);
    document.querySelector("#jjquery").setAttribute("src", "/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js");
    document.querySelector("#jscookie").setAttribute("src", "/js/jscookie.js");

  }

  function onLoadJquery() {
    // safely import the rest of the scripts
    document.querySelector("#winx").setAttribute("src", "/js/winx.js");
  }
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Why set an HTML attribute to add an event handler? You could just use `document.querySelector("#jjquery").addEventHandler("load", onLoadJquery)`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey it has been the standard since the beginning, `addEventListener` is supported since IE9, of course you can use it too.

Comment: If I use Rodrigo Ferreira's code, my jquery-dependent script just doesn't work, without any errors or anything. If I use the line from Heretic Monkey instead, it throws an error `document.querySelector(...).addEventHandler is not a function` (on Firefox 65).

Comment: @ErikGordon I think Heretic Monkey was referring to `addEventListener`

Comment: Indeed, it worked now. Thank you both. Neither I would be able to come up with a search request like that to find that other question, nor I would be able to apply the answer from there to my case.

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira if you edit your answer and replace `document.querySelector("#jjquery").setAttribute("onload", onLoadJquery);` with `document.querySelector("#jjquery").addEventListener("load", onLoadJquery);`, I'll choose it as accepted, because your original answer didn't work.

Comment: @ErikGordon I applied the change that you suggested